# Drupal 7 crashes after Entity module install

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I would like to ask how is possible to disable a module in drupal 7 via database? I wanted to enable the Entity module which is required to use View_Bulk_Operations module, but when I clicked on the "Enable" button I got an error message regarding filesystem permissions. A file or files are not readable. According to my FTP access every file is readable. Unfortunately, the whole site is crashed.

I'm able to reach the database and the webserver filesystem, but there is no chance to use the drupal's administration forms.

My question is how possible to disable a module using the database?

I already deleted the modules files from the filesystem and there is a registry table which contains the files properties, those rows which contains the Entity module file properties are already deleted but the site does not work. What should I do more?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

From your database manager, open `system` table.

Then find the module you want and change status value to `0`.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, but there is no "entity" module according to this table. I restored the site from backup.